# Neo4j , Relationship deletion causing exception

Tags: neo4j

I am facing strange problem in deleting relationship.

I think it is some kind of deadlock occurring. 
Here is the code

```
Transaction txBegin = graphDb.beginTx();

try {
    for (Relationship r : GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDb).getAllRelationships()) {
        for(String indexName : graphDb.index().relationshipIndexNames()) {
            graphDb.index().forRelationships(indexName).remove(r);
        }
    }
    r.delete(); // EXCEPTION HERE
}
```

Here is the stack trace I got

```
Thread [16462692@qtp-14650787-39 - /db/data/ext/MyGraph/graphdb/deleteAll] (Suspended)  
waiting for: RWLock  (id=90)    
Object.wait(long) line: not available [native method]   
RWLock(Object).wait() line: 503 
RWLock.acquireWriteLock(Transaction) line: 341  
LockManagerImpl.getWriteLock(Object, Transaction) line: 133 
WritableTransactionState.acquireWriteLock(Object) line: 279 
NodeManager.deleteRelationship(RelationshipImpl, TransactionState) line: 837    
OldTxStateBridgeImpl.deleteRelationship(long) line: 150 
TxStateImpl.relationshipDoDelete(long) line: 263    
StateHandlingStatementOperations.relationshipDelete(Statement, long) line: 90   
ConstraintEnforcingEntityWriteOperations.relationshipDelete(Statement, long) line: 143  
LockingStatementOperations.relationshipDelete(Statement, long) line: 188    
DataStatement.relationshipDelete(long) line: 62 
RelationshipProxy.delete() line: 86 
MyGraph.deleteAll(GraphDatabaseService) line: 188   
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Transaction marked for rollback

Comment: Can you include the entire stack trace? From what you describe, it sounds like somewhere you have already completed the transaction by the time you are trying to delete.

Comment: @Nicholas : I am digging some more .. I found that sometimes control lost at command r.delete() while debugging in eclipse .

Comment: @Nicholas : If I am correct Then I did the following to get Stack Trace . First Suspend the running thread then copy the stack trace. What I found is that It is waiting for RWLOCk .. I think thats why it keeps running forever ..

Comment: Neo4j should do deadlock detection on those locks. In your try/catch, print out the stacktrace of the error situation and put it in the original question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38648/discussion-between-voila-and-nicholas)